# Keep on running an app after the screen auto-locks - Phonegap (Android/iOS)

Tags: android, ios, cordova, background-process, auto-lock

I am developing an app that tracks the users movement over GPS (bike riding in particular) and  I realized that when the screen auto-locks, the app would stop running (if I'm not mistaken, I'm not completely certain on this).

Is there a way to prevent the phone from auto-locking? Or as an alternative, is there a way (by using Phonegap) to keep on tracking the user's movement after the screen auto-locks (as a background process of some sort)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure you need to use a `Service` for this. `Services` can be started by `Activities` to run in the background - i.e. you could start the `Service` in the `onPause()` method of your `Activity`.

> A service is a component that runs in the background to perform
>   long-running operations or to perform work for remote processes. A
>   service does not provide a user interface. For example, a service
>   might play music in the background while the user is in a different
>   application, or it might fetch data over the network without blocking
>   user interaction with an activity. Another component, such as an
>   activity, can start the service and let it run or bind to it in order
>   to interact with it.

**Source:** http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html

Google provides developers with a guide to using `Services` on the Android developer site. Here's the direct link: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/services.html

Comment: Most of us know we can use service to keep the android app running in the backgroud. But how to start a service from Android's Phonegap SDK... dats the issue.... :(

Answer (score 1):

You can use [service](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/services.html) for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a plugin that start a service. Add callbacks and methods to the plugin to get notifications or to retrieve information. Plugin is basically a communication layer between Cordova/Phonegap and native.